# Phonegap file storage of local files

Tags: jquery, cordova

Is it possible to store the Jquery-1.7.2.mins.js with in side the build?  This way the app does not have to download the file every time the application is launched and reducing the time it takes for the app to complete it's launch

Comment: Absolutely. Just store it in the `www` folder, much like you would on a regular website (so perhaps add a `js` folder inside of www).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Just include it in the www directory and have your
html link to it relatively.